# Mapping Code Value between two Collections making updating values using other collection

Tags: mongodb, mgo

I have two collections.

I am using MongoDB version 3.4.

Collection 1 called `Results`

Collection 2 called `Code_Value`

**Here i have  to update automatically the code in the `result` using the `Code_value` Collections**

The `results` is like:

```
{
_id: ObjectId(xxxxxxx)
name:"Mike"
job:"3"
salary:"4"
}

{
_id: ObjectId(xxxxxxx)
name:"Joe"
job:"1"
salary:"2"
}
```

the `Code_value` is like:

```
{ 
 "Job":[ 
        {"code":"1" , "value":"IT"}
        {"code":"2" , "value":"Doctor"}
        {"code":"3" , "value":"Developer"}

      ]

 "Salary":[ 
        {"code":"1" , "value":"900000"}
        {"code":"2" , "value":"100000"}
        {"code":"3" , "value":"200000"}
        {"code":"4" , "value":"300000"}

      ]

}
```

I'd like to have a mapping code value on the results as the following:

```
 {
 _id: ObjectId(xxxxxxx)
 name:"Mike"
 job:"Developer"
 salary:"300000"
 }

 {
_id: ObjectId(xxxxxxx)
 name:"Joe"
 job:"IT"
 salary:"100000"
 }
```

here is  the query made as function

```
 results.find().foreach(cursor){
 v=Code_value.find(cursor,code)
 if(v){
 results.update(job,v.value)
                               }
```

Comment: You have to use [MongoDB aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) for such query, and use the community supported driver [`github.com/globalsign/mgo`](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo).

Comment: @Neil Lunn i edited the question  thanks for the notice maybe i did not explain well the problem , please could you see it again thanks

Comment: @icza thanks i changed to it , but the problem of query still not working , could you please guide or give a help please ?